# fullcalendar.io 5: addEventSource not work from external function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

For a small project I want to add events at runtime.

The actual calendar is created with data from a database. The separate script creates additional events, which are created dynamically at runtime of the calendar. These events should be added to the existing calendar afterwards.

For testing I have a calendar and an external button. If you click on the button, an event should be added to the calendar. Calendar is created and the click is recognized. But no event is added.

Where is the thought error?

The HTML

```
<button class="holiday">Add Feiertage</button>
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

The Code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek'
    },
    initialDate: '2020-11-12',
    businessHours: true, // display business hours
    editable: true,
    events: [
      {
        title: 'Business Lunch',
        start: '2020-11-03T13:00:00',
        constraint: 'businessHours'
      },
      {
        title: 'Meeting',
        start: '2020-11-13T11:00:00',
        constraint: 'availableForMeeting', // defined below
        color: '#257e4a'
      },
      {
        title: 'Conference',
        start: '2020-11-18',
        end: '2020-11-20'
      },
      {
        title: 'Party',
        start: '2020-11-29T20:00:00'
      },

      // areas where "Meeting" must be dropped
      {
        groupId: 'availableForMeeting',
        start: '2020-11-11T10:00:00',
        end: '2020-11-11T16:00:00',
        display: 'background'
      },
      {
        groupId: 'availableForMeeting',
        start: '2020-11-13T10:00:00',
        end: '2020-11-13T16:00:00',
        display: 'background'
      },

      // red areas where no events can be dropped
      {
        start: '2020-11-18',
        title: 'Test-Holiday',
        overlap: false,
        display: 'background',
        color: '#ff9f89'
      }
    ]
  });

  calendar.render();
});

// external events by Click
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('.holiday').on('click', function() {
   console.log('klick');

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl);

    //var src = calendar.getEventSources(); // give me a empty array

    calendar.addEventSource(
      {
        events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
          {
            title  : 'Test-Event',
            start  : '2020-11-11',
            overlap: false,
            display: 'background',
            color: '#ff9f89'
          }
        ]
      });
    calendar.refetchEvents();
  });
 });
});
```

Here is my Test:
https://jsfiddle.net/LukasHH/tu14xfwr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `calendar` variable you're using for `calendar.addEventSource` refers to a different FullCalendar instance than the one which is shown on your page. You have created a completely new calendar - but then didn't render it to the page. That's why you don't get errors, but also nothing useful happens.

The original `calendar` is defined and populated inside your `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {` block, but you tried to create a new one inside your `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` block. You need to use the existing reference to `calendar` - but of course it's out of scope when you need it, because you're in a different code block.

Now, `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {` and `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {` are essentially equivalent, it's just that one is written in native JS and one is jQuery syntax. They basically do the same task - i.e. delay execution of the code until the DOM is completely loaded. Therefore it doesn't make much sense or add any value to have both of them in the page at the same time. Just use one block to include all of your code, and then you won't have any scope problems regardless.

As well as that, for similar reasons it also makes no sense to have another `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {` *within* the jQuery "ready" block! You simply don't need it. I can only assume you didn't understand what that code did and thought it was part of fullCalendar - it's not.

And

```
var i = calendar.initialEvents();
console.log(i);
```

makes no sense. There's no method called initialEvents in fullCalendar and you don't seem to be trying to use `i` for anything anyway, so you can just remove these lines.

e.g.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    //...etc
  });
  calendar.render();

  $('.holiday').on('click', function() {
    calendar.addEventSource({
      events: [ // put the array in the `events` property
      {
        title: 'Test-Event',
        start: '2020-11-11',
        overlap: false,
        display: 'background',
        color: '#ff9f89'
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/32w4kLvg/

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. But I might have to explain it a bit more detailed.

What I simulate here comes from 2 different projects / scripts that are independent of each other.

The first script (Joomla component) is the basic calendar with all settings and events. Here fixed events are stored in a database and displayed in the calendar. This is finished and is not from me. (But I am already in contact with the developer)

Comment: The second script (Joomla Plugin) works separately and should add dynamic events to the existing calendar (background events). The dynamic events are generated at runtime of the calendar. These are for example holidays, birthdays, repeating days (every 2nd wednesday) and so on.

My first approach was to access the instance of the existing calendar to add the dynamic events. 2nd approach I get the data from the existing calendar, add the dynamic events and create a new calendar.

Comment: ok. But either way you are going to need access to the instance of the existing calendar (and in that case, only approach 1 really makes sense - no point in creating a new calendar if you can access the existing one). So yes the developer of the original plugin might have to change it to make the calendar instance accessible in some way (either make it global, or through some API to the plugin code) - or you can amend it yourself of course in the meantime.

Comment: But I answered the question as it was posed - You did say it was a "separate script", but the way you built the JSFiddle made it look like it was really all code within one page which could be merged, and so I took the "separate" bit to mean it was simply a new bit of code you had tried to add on later, rather than actually coming from totally different 3rd party plugins. I can only answer with what's provided, and it works to answer what's provided - and I did diagnose the root cause of the problem correctly too - so I feel the answer should be accepted as-is :-).